# Do items with curse of vanishing disappear from shulker boxes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Curse of vanishing is an enchantment that destroys item once you die, it's not useful in single player, but is useful in multiplayer. I'm wondering if they disappear from shulker boxes if you die?

Comment: This would be a good question if it was self-answered. This way I just wonder why you didn't just try it.

Comment: I think curse of vanishing can be useful in single player adventure maps, but in normal survival I'd avoid it in both single player and multiplayer co-op

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## No.

The contents of shulker boxes and your ender chest are not affected by curse of vanishing.

Comment: This is actually a bug: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-110907 It was meant to be fixed in 19w37a, but wasn't. So this answer is still correct.

Comment: Apparently it is actually intended: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-109053

Answer (score 9):

No they don't. only items in your inventory will disappear when you die.